# Trapezoid and line connecting two sides

Tags: geometry

Base sides of trapezoid are 8 and 6. Parallel line to base sides that connects two other sides splits trapezoid to two surfaces with equal area. 
What is the length of this line?

My attempt: I tried drawing figure and manipulating formulas, to no avail for finding the length of this side.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

"Complete" upto a triangle and work with triangles in Thales position.

Answer (score 0):

Write area of each of the small trapezes in terms of the area of the original one. We use the bases of the original trapeze as $L_{1,2}$, the middle line is $L$, and the distance between $L$ and $L_{1,2}$ is $h_{1,2}$:$$\frac{L+L_1}{2}h_1=\frac12\frac{L_1+L_2}{2}(h_1+h_2)\\\frac{L+L_2}{2}h_2=\frac12\frac{L_1+L_2}{2}(h_1+h_2)$$
Now let's group terms with $h_1$ and $h_2$ on opposite sides of each equation:
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{L+L_1}{2}-\frac{L_1+L_2}{4}\right)h_1&=\frac{L_1+L_2}{4}h_2\\\frac{L_1+L_2}{4}h_1&=\left(\frac{L+L_2}{2}-\frac{L_1+L_2}{4}\right)h_2
\end{align}$$ 
Simplifying the expressions in parenthesis, and taking the ratio of the two equations yields:
$$\frac{2L+L_1-L_2}{L_1+L_2}=\frac{L_1+L_2}{2L+L_2-L_1}$$
This is equivalent to $$(2L+(L_2-L_1))(2L-(L_2-L_1))=(L_1+L_2)^2$$
or: $$4L^2-(L_2-L_1)^2=(L_1+L_2)^2$$
Then the final answer is $$L=\frac12\sqrt{(L_1+L_2)^2+(L_2-L_1)^2}=\sqrt{50}$$